# Why plane is rendered 2 times in Unity 3D?

Tags: 3d, rendering, shader, unity-game-engine

Firstly, I want to say sorry to you, I can't upload image right after each line It should be, because my reputation is not enough (can not even post more than 2 image in 1 question).

Here is the drive link of all images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0By4CxzQWUmEQTm9FQVJ5UzFBc0k?usp=sharing

I'm making a game using Unity3D and the FogOfWar lib. It's using a plane with these components : (please see in Drive link, thanks)
The mesh filter is re-created when start :

```
    halfPlaneSize = (float)planeSize * 0.5f;
    nodeSize = 1f / (float)nodeResolution;
    vertCount = ((int)(planeSize * nodeResolution)) + 1;

    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    mesh.Clear();

    Vector3 offset = new Vector3(-halfPlaneSize, 0, -halfPlaneSize);
    Vector3[] vs = this.vs = new Vector3[vertCount * vertCount];
    Vector2[] uvs = this.uvs = new Vector2[vs.Length];
    revealedArea = new bool[vs.Length];

    int[] tris = new int[(vertCount - 1) * (vertCount - 1) * 6];

    for (int r = 0; r < vertCount; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < vertCount; ++c)
        {
            int i = r + (vertCount * c);

            vs[i] = offset + new Vector3(r * nodeSize, 0f, c * nodeSize);

            if (terrain != null)
            {
                vs[i].y = terrain.SampleHeight(transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(vs[i].x, 0, vs[i].z)));
            }
        }
    }

    if (useFadingOrBlockyShader)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vs.Length; ++i)
        {
            uvs[i] = new Vector2(-100f, -100f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vs.Length; ++i)
        {
            uvs[i] = new Vector2(fogInstantDarkness, fogInstantDarkness); // 1f
        }
    }

    int t = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < vertCount - 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < vertCount - 1; x++)
        {
            tris[t] = (y * vertCount) + x;
            tris[t + 1] = ((y + 1) * vertCount) + x;
            tris[t + 2] = (y * vertCount) + x + 1;

            tris[t + 3] = ((y + 1) * vertCount) + x;
            tris[t + 4] = ((y + 1) * vertCount) + x + 1;
            tris[t + 5] = (y * vertCount) + x + 1;
            t += 6;
        }
    }

    mesh.vertices = vs;
    mesh.uv = uvs;
    mesh.triangles = tris;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

The Update() function :

```
void Update()
{
    frameCount += 1;
    UpdateFog = frameCount >= updateEveryNFrames || UpdateFog || ClearAll;
    if (frameCount >= updateEveryNFrames)
    {
        UpdateFogForVisibilityChecker = true;
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateFogForVisibilityChecker = false;
    }
    if (ClearAll)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < uvs.Length; ++i)
        {
            uvs[i].x = fogInstantDarkness;
        }

        ClearAll = false;
    }

    if (UpdateFog)
    {
        if (useFadingOrBlockyShader) // I don't enable this
        {
            revealValue = Time.time;
        }
        else
        {
            //If we're updating fog, make it all black //old
            for (int i = 0; i < uvs.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (revealedArea[i]) // if that area was revealed before, make it less dark
                {
                    uvs[i].x = fogLessDarkness;
                }
                else // if that area wasn't revealed before, make it black
                {
                    uvs[i].x = fogInstantDarkness;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("_WorldTime", revealValue);
}
```

There're another objects using this code to reveal an area with radius around these :

```
public void Reveal(Vector3 pos, float radius)
{
    pos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(pos);

    int r = Mathf.RoundToInt(((planeSize / 2f) + pos.x) * nodeResolution);
    int c = Mathf.RoundToInt(((planeSize / 2f) + pos.z) * nodeResolution);
    int center = r + (vertCount * c);

    if (r >= 0 && r < vertCount && c >= 0 && c < vertCount && center < uvs.Length)
    {
        radius *= nodeResolution;

        int row = Mathf.Clamp(r - (int)radius, 0, int.MaxValue);
        int col = Mathf.Clamp(c - (int)radius, 0, int.MaxValue);

        int row_end = Mathf.Clamp(r + (int)radius, 0, vertCount);
        int col_end = Mathf.Clamp(c + (int)radius, 0, vertCount);

        int row_mid = (row+row_end)/2;

        int col_mid = (col+col_end)/2;

        float sqr = radius * radius;

        Vector3 v = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 ct = new Vector3(r, c);

        for (; row < row_end; ++row)
        {
            col = Mathf.Clamp(c - (int)radius, 0, int.MaxValue);

            for (; col < col_end; ++col)
            {
                v = new Vector3(row, col);

                float sqr_to_target = (ct - v).sqrMagnitude;
                if (sqr_to_target < sqr)
                {
                    float radius_per = sqr_to_target/sqr;                       
                    radius_per*=radius_per;
                    int tmp = row + (vertCount * col);
                    uvs[tmp].x*= radius_per;

                    revealedArea[tmp] = true; //reveal that area
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Summary of the Reveal() function : create a square around the pos, then check which points in that square are inside the circle (center = pos, radius = radius), reveal these points by changing the alpha.

Here's the shader code which this plane use :

```
Shader "Mobile/Fog of War (Instant - Faded)" {  
Properties {  }  
Subshader {
Tags { "Queue"="Overlay-50" "RenderType"="Transparent" }

Pass {  
    Cull Back 
    Lighting Off 
    ZWrite Off
    ZTest Always
    Blend Zero OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Fog { Mode Off }

    CGPROGRAM

    #pragma vertex vert_img
    #pragma fragment frag

    struct appdata_img {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    struct v2f_img {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    v2f_img vert_img( appdata_img v )
    {
        v2f_img o;

        o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
        o.uv = v.texcoord;

        return o;
    }

    float4 frag (v2f_img i) : COLOR
    {   
        return float4(1, 1, 1, i.uv.x);
    }

    ENDCG
}
}
}
```

I notice that as soon as I active the revealer, everything work well like this image : (please see in Drive link, thanks)

After that, just a blink, seem it's rendered again, it become worse like this : (please see in Drive link, thanks)

I don't know in deep how Unity processing. Could you tell me why this happen, and very nice if there're some ways to keep it stay at the first state (good state). If you need further information, please tell me then I'll update immediately.

Thanks for reading.

Here's the Drive link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0By4CxzQWUmEQTm9FQVJ5UzFBc0k?usp=sharing

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to maximize the chances of your question being answered.